# Difference of methods defined on this in contrast to defined in class body

Tags: javascript, es6-class

What is the difference between when I add a method to all instances of a class in the constructor via

```
this.bar = function() {}
```

as opposed to defining the function right in the class body

```
baz() {}
```

?

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = function() {};
  }
  
  baz() {}
}

console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(new Foo, 'bar')); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(new Foo, 'baz')); // false
```

If I simply replace `this.baz` with `this.baz` in the constructor, both tests return `true`:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = function() {};
    this.baz = this.baz;
  }
  
  baz() {}
}

console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(new Foo, 'bar')); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(new Foo, 'baz')); // true now
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Did you miread `baz` for `bar` in the first snippet?

Comment: Yup. The point at which I need to start wearing my glasses (or maybe just pay more attention!) keeps moving earlier in the afternoon... :-|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `this.bar = function() { };` in the constructor, you're creating a new function for every instance, and assigning it to the `bar` property. This lets the function *close over* something in the constructor if you want it to. (And if you used an arrow function, the function would close over `this` and `super`.)

When you declare a method in the `class`, you're creating a single function on the prototype object that class will assign to instances, and reusing that function. This lets the function use `super` if it needs to access superclass features.

Both have their place depending on what you're doing. You can see that difference here:

```js
class Foo1 {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = function() {};
    }
}

class Foo2 {
    bar() {}
}

const f1a = new Foo1();
const f1b = new Foo1();
console.log(f1a.bar === f1b.bar); // false

const f2a = new Foo2();
const f2b = new Foo2();
console.log(f2a.bar === f2b.bar); // true
```

About this:

```
this.baz = this.baz;
```

in

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = function() {};
//             vvvvvvvv−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− reads from the prototype
    this.baz = this.baz;
//  ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− writes to the instance

  }
  
  baz() {}
}
```

that's looking up the function on the prototype, and then assigning it directly on the object, which is why it becomes an own property after that assignment.

Comment: I would add that defining the method in the class definition (which puts the method once on the prototype for all instances to share) is generally more efficient and should be the preferred way of doing things unless you have a specific reason to assign it in the constructor.

Comment: I used to think in terms of "either the instance has the property or the class has it, in which case it's static". So what would `baz` be called in the first example? A class method?

Comment: @connexo no, static properties are something else. What you call "class method" is just a prototype method (property). You should maybe read about prototypes. JS actually goes discretely down all the prototype chain when you try to access a property, if it exists in the prototype chain, it returns it whether it's the direct prototype or further down the chain. Classes are just a synctatic sugar of it

Comment: @connexo - In the first example it's an *instance* method. In the second example it's a *prototype* method. A *static* (or *class*) method would be one available without an instance, such as `Foo.example()`, which you either declare with the `static` keyword (in which case it has access to `super` to refer to the constructor it inherits from) or add as a property after the fact.

Comment: @connexo - FWIW, I go into classes in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 4 of my new book; links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: I just pre-ordered your book, which in Germany has not yet been published.

Comment: This whole *reads from the prototype - assigns to the instance" thing seems like an aspect worth going into detail in a book. It is a very common pattern to e.g. re-bind event handlers in CustomElements in the constructor like `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`. I wasn't aware that this actually creates a difference on that hasOwnProperty checks.

Comment: @connexo - Great! I don't know what's taking so long getting copies to people in Germany. I mean, it's 2020 folks!

Comment: @connexo - Yup, the purpose of that pattern is to put the function on the prototype where it can be reused, inherited, mocked for testing purposes, etc., but then create a version on the instance as an own property that has the instance bound to it, so you don't have to worry about dealing with `this` when assigning it as an event handler, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Even if that binding purpose is simply being able to access other prototype properties...

Comment: @connexo - I don't quite follow what you mean there. The main thing is when `this` would otherwise point to something else entirely during the call (like an HTML element instance) and you don't want to have to deal with that every time you assign it as a handler.

Comment: So does that mean that `class Foo { constructor() { this.prototype.baz = function() {}; } }` and `class Foo { baz() {} }` do achieve the same result?

Comment: I mean that binding pattern creates a fresh copy of that function on every instance, and there's no alternative to doing that, even if all you need is access to other prototype properties of the object.

Comment: @connexo - No, for a couple of reasons: 1. That would throw an error because by default there is no `prototype` property on non-functions, and 2. With method syntax, the methods are added to the prototype at class instantiation time, not at instance instantiation time. In general, never write to prototypes in instance constructors.

Comment: @connexo - *"I mean that binding pattern creates a fresh copy of that function on every instance..."* It creates a new function object, yes, but a thin one that just turns around and calls the original.

Comment: So there is no way of binding a prototype method without making it an instance method, right?

Comment: @connexo - You don't have to store it on the instance, but if you're giving a function to something that will call it with `this` set to something other than what you want `this` set to, you only have three options: Create a bound function via `bind`, create an arrow function that closes over the `this` you want to use, or create a function that closes over other stuff you want to use and don't use `this`. All of which have "create a function" in common. :-) But don't worry about doing that, JavaScript engines are **very** efficient at it.

Comment: I'm not worried about performance, I'm currently writing unit tests for a web component library that is based on class inheritance. In those, I do require certain objects to have an own implementation of a method, or have a static own implementation, which is why I'm doing alot of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call()`-stuff. And casually changing where methods are located is not so nice if you don't **know** when this happens. That caused my question.